# sql two where clauses from one table into two new rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tableA:

```
column A    | column B    | column C
-------------------------------------
1           |10           |a
2           |10           |b
3           |10           |c
4           |10           |d

5           |20           |a
6           |20           |b
7           |20           |c
8           |20           |d

9           |30           |a
10          |30           |b
11          |30           |c
12          |30           |d
```

I want to get this output:

```
column A-10  | column A-20    | column C
-------------------------------------
1            |5                |a
2            |6                |b
3            |7                |c
4            |8                |d
```

I tried this SQL query:

```
From tableA select column A, column C WHERE column B = 10
```

Which works and gives me the expected results. However if I add a second WHERE clauses

```
From tableA select column A, column C WHERE column B = 10 AND column B = 20
```

I get an empty return. How to the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select max(case when b = 10 then a end) as a_10,
       max(case when b = 20 then a end) as a_20,
       c
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c, b order by a) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by c, seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use join operator here.

```
select
    t1.A as a10
    ,t2.A as a20
    ,t1.C as c
from (
    select column A, column C From tableA WHERE column B = 10
    ) t1
    inner join (
    select column A, column C From tableA WHERE column B = 20
    ) t2
    on t1.C = t2.C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both 10 AND 20 which is why it is blank when it is run.

You can however have 10 OR 20.

Swap out AND for OR and it should get you the result you're looking for.

Comment: True but I need the outcome in separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Correct query:

```
select  tab1.A as a10 ,tab2.A as a20 ,tab1.C as c
from (
    select column A, column C From tableA WHERE column B = 10
    ) tab1, 
    (
    select column A, column C From tableA WHERE column B = 20
    ) tab2
where tab.C = tab.C
```

Comment: This results in always the same value in column a20